# how can i create a page transition with preact

Tags: javascript, typescript, preact, preact-router

I'm trying to get a page transition using `preact-router`, i already tried the `preact-transition-group` package with the `preact-css-transition-group` package, that gives me an error, anyways here is my basic setup:

```
import { h, FunctionComponent } from 'preact';
import Router from 'preact-router';

const App: FunctionComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div path="/1" style="padding: 50px">
        page 1 <a href="/2">page 2</a>
      </div>
      <div path="/2" style="padding: 50px">
        page 2 <a href="/1">page 1</a>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

a typescript and/or `preact-router` solution is preferable but not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note: that this approach probably dosn't work with nested routes.

With this approach you need to wrap every route in a div with a class that will animate the route and set the key and path attribute to the path of the route like this:

```
function wrapRoute(route: h.JSX.Element): h.JSX.Element {
  return ( // the in class is the animation and the page class is makes sure that the old and new routes overlap
    <div path={route.props.path} class="in page" key={route.props.path}>
      {route}
    </div>
  );
}
```

then you need to add two reactive variables like this:

```
const [previousEl, setPreviousEl] = useState<ComponentChildren | null>(null);
const [outEl, setOutEl] = useState<JSX.Element | null>(null);
```

after that you can listen to the `onChange` event of the `preact-router` and set the `outEl` to a div that wraps `previousEl` and has a class that will animate the exit of the route, then add a `onAnimationEnd` listener so that you can set the `outEl` to `null` one the out animation has finished, last thing you need to set the `previousEl` to `e.current.props.children`, your router component listener should look like this:

```
<Router onChange={(e) => {
  if (previousEl) {
    setOutEl(
      <div class="out page" key={e.previous} onAnimationEnd={() => setOutEl(null)}>
        {previousEl}
      </div>
    );
  }
  if (e.current) {
    setPreviousEl(e.current.props.children);
  }
}}
>
{routes} // this is an array containing all the wrapped routes.
</Router>
```

last thing you need to do is to create the animations, look at the `app.sass` example below.

here is the full example:

app.tsx

```
import { h, FunctionComponent, JSX, ComponentChildren, Fragment } from 'preact';
import Router from 'preact-router';
import { useState } from 'preact/hooks';
import './app.sass'

const routes = [
  <div style="padding: 50px; background: red" path="/1">
    page 1 <a href="/2">page 2</a> <a href="/3">page 3</a>
  </div>,
  <div style="padding: 50px; background: blue" path="/2">
    page 2 <a href="/1">page 1</a> <a href="/3">page 3</a>
  </div>,
  <div style="padding: 50px; background: green" path="/3">
    page 2 <a href="/1">page 1</a> <a href="/2">page 2</a>
  </div>,
].map((route) => wrapRoute(route));

function wrapRoute(route: h.JSX.Element): h.JSX.Element {
  return (
    <div path={route.props.path} class="in page" key={route.props.path}>
      {route}
    </div>
  );
}

const App: FunctionComponent = () => {
  const [previousEl, setPreviousEl] = useState<ComponentChildren | null>(null);
  const [outEl, setOutEl] = useState<JSX.Element | null>(null);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Router
        onChange={(e) => {
          if (previousEl) {
            setOutEl(
              <div class="out page" key={e.previous} onAnimationEnd={() => setOutEl(null)}>
                {previousEl}
              </div>
            );
          }
          if (e.current) {
            setPreviousEl(e.current.props.children);
          }
        }}
      >
        {routes}
      </Router>
      {outEl}
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default App;
```

app.sass

```
.page
  position: absolute
  top: 0
  bottom: 0
  left: 0
  right: 0

.out
  animation: out 200ms forwards

@keyframes out
  0%
    opacity: 1
    transform: translateX(0)
  100%
    opacity: 0
    transform: translateX(100vw)

.in
  animation: in 200ms forwards

@keyframes in
  0%
    opacity: 0
    transform: translateX(-100vw)
  100%
    opacity: 1
    transform: translateX(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create an animation is introducing another HOC - Higher Order Component that wraps your page and use that as a router target. It would be something like:

```
import { h, FunctionComponent } from 'preact';
import Router from 'preact-router';

const App: FunctionComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <PageAnimation path="/1">
          <div style="padding: 50px">
            page 1 <a href="/2">page 2</a>
          </div>
      </PageAnimation>
      <PageAnimation path="/2">
        <div style="padding: 50px">
          page 2 <a href="/1">page 1</a>
        </div>
      </PageAnimation>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

Your implementation code would be something like - 
[How to make transition animation](https://github.com/preactjs/preact/issues/92#issuecomment-236365058).